# How do you set Flymake to use a Makefile in a different directory?

Tags: emacs

I have a code folder with a root directory and all of the build system (including the Makefile) located in ./build/

Whenever I try to do M-x flymake-mode for files in the root directory or other subdirectories, it says it can't find the Makefile. I tried the following elisp code, but it didn't help any:

```
(setq flymake-buildfile-dirs '("./build/" "../build/"))
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this configuration to work properly?